# Will Windows OS Support be added back in 5.x

Tags: cassandra

Do we plan to re-include windows OS support in the latest version ?
We bundle it in our software which gives support for both the OS types Linux and Windows. Since version 4.x, Windows support is removed and we are not able to upgrade to the latest version of Cassandra.

Comment: That might be a good question for the supplier.

Comment: You can use Cassandra 4 with WSL2 and it should be the way to go. Windows Support is a pain for (any) maintainers. I have not seen any effort in that direction https://github.com/apache/cassandra/pull/328 "FROM Cassandra 4"

Comment: Worth noting, but even Microsoft wasn't running Cassandra on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

There are currently no CEP proposals nor any listed items on the published roadmap of Cassandra 5.0 for Windows support to be re-introduced. You have the option as Cedrick mentioned to use WSL, but I think using a docker container may be more suitable / easier to deploy and run as a part of an overall 'bundle', with the ability for you to pre-configure the container(s) as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to chime in and second Aaron's point here. Context: was lead on Windows support, pushed for the 2.2 release so we had Windows support sans Storage Engine rewrite, and am who Aaron quoted above. :)

Windows definitely had some really solid perf numbers in the memory-mapped case, but ultimately as a production runtime environment for high performance java apps, there remain some pretty glaring pain points. Hard-links not being able to be deleted was one pain point; showed up in the sstable early re-opening we had to delete, in snapshots accumulating and needing a hacking handle registration that'd delete files on JVM shutdown, and in a bunch of other small subtle places.

Another big issue was the coalescing timer on Windows: see [this link here](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2020/10/04/windows-timer-resolution-the-great-rule-change/) for some deep diving into the difficulty with it. The TL;DR on it: in order to get consistent performance out of the server on Windows (i.e. get threads woken up on a regular cadence for epoll response to what's on the network), I ended up having to use what's considered a "multimedia timer" that kind of forces the system-wide timer into overdrive and, instead of coalescing on 15ms+ intervals, had it wake up every ms. Really good for fixing those performance numbers; not so good for the environment if we have 100's of thousands of servers out in the world running C* on Windows and burning through CPU cycles needlessly. As an amusing anecdote, I figured this out when I realized my stress runs were *far faster* when I had IRC open for some reason. Turned out the IRC client was setting that coalescing timer window which has a system-wide effect.

So anyway, long story short - WSL (particularly w/version 2.0) has really made a night and day difference in terms of the ease of use of development of linux-based env on Windows, and I personally wouldn't recommend running java-based high performance processes on a Windows-based environment, specifically LSM-trees, given some of the above realities of the environment.

Assuming someone wanted to step forward and contribute 1st class citizen Windows support, it wasn't too disruptive to the existing codebase, and they were interested in maintaining it, the project would 100% be receptive to talking about it. But right now, none of the active contributors are focused on that and have no plans to return to it.

Answer (score 0):

**No!**

There was a [discussion about this on the mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@cassandra.apache.org/msg15583.html), which ultimately led to the removal of Windows support from Cassandra 4.0.  The reasons for it can be found in the discussion, but are mostly related to issues with NTFS.  These were detailed by (current) PMC Chair Josh McKenzie who put it best in [CASSANDRA-16171](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16171) when he said:

> Windows has a much stricter policy on deletion of hard links to
> actively open file handles compared to linux. Namely, they don't let
> you do it. Given the architecture of the LSM trees in C* this was just
> a painful match to begin with and something that repeatedly led to
> annoyances and deferred file cleanup and deletion on various
> features.

Suffice to say, that native support for Cassandra on Windows is gone, and it is not coming back.